# Macro define for type is not working

Tags: c++

why is the following code not working?

```
// Template function definition
template <typename T>
void apply(const T& input);

// Helper macro definition
#define APPLY_FUNCTION(PIXELTYPE) \
  apply<##PIXELTYPE>(input);

// Use macro to call function
APPLY_FUNCTION(uint8_t);
```

This yields the following error:

> Error: pasting "<" and "uint8_t" does not give a valid preprocessing
>   token

Comment: Even if you fix the macro where are you getting `input` to pass to the function?

Comment: Macros are not terminated by semicolons.

Comment: Not saying you're wrong, but having that `input` inside your macro doesn't seem to be the best practice you could choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to specify the type of the template parameter anyway?  If you don't specifically want a macro then just using your apply function directly will work just fine:

```
    template <class T>
    void apply(const T & input)
    {
        //...
    }

    apply(1.0f); // Will instantiate apply<float> to match the input's type
```

If you want the type `T` to be different from what is passed in, then I would suggest the following template instead:

```
    template <class T, class Input>
    void apply(const Input & input)
    {
        T t(input);
        //...
    }
```

Which can then be called with:

```
    apply<uint8_t>(1.0f);
```

And there's no need for this macro at all.

Answer (score 8):

`##` is for pasting tokens together. You don't need that, so just:

```
#define APPLY_FUNCTION(PIXELTYPE) apply<PIXELTYPE>(input);
```

That said, two guidelines:

1. Don't end your macro with a `;` Requiring the user to add it will save you from some bugs.
2. Please don't write this macro.

Answer (score 0):

In a macro expansion, `##` tells the compiler to combine the token that precedes it with the token that follows it and treat the result as a single token. As the error message says, `<uint8_t` is not a valid token. Just get rid of the `##`.